# AppVeyor CI - Azure App Service Multiple Environment Deployments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, continuous-integration, appveyor, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an Asp.Net MVC project that deploys to an Azure App Service via AppVeyor, with an appveyor.yml file that is configured to deploy GitHub commits to both Production and Staging.

**The configuration is -**

- Master branch, use Release configuration.
- Staging branch, use Staging configuration.

The staging deployment builds and deploys without issue, however, the staging deployment still targets the "Release" configuration, despite it being set to "Staging" for the Staging branch. I can see this as when I login to staging, it is pointing at the Staging Azure SQL database.

**Local Testing**

I have tested it locally in Staging configuration, and it works in that regard.

I'm assuming the appveyor.yml file is configured incorrectly, and thus AppVeyor is not picking up the Staging configuration?

```
version: 1.0.{build}

build_script:
  - ps: .\build.cmd CreateNuGet

nuget:
  account_feed: true

artifacts:
  - path: output\*.*

test: off

for:
# configuration for "master" branch
# build in Release mode and deploy to the Azure prod environment
-
  branches:
    only:
      - master
  configuration: Release

  deploy:
    provider: WebDeploy
    server: [removed for brevity]
    website: [removed for brevity]
    username: [removed for brevity]
    password: [removed for brevity]
    ntlm: false
    remove_files: true
    app_offline: false

# configuration for "staging" branch
# build in Staging mode and deploy to the Azure staging environment
-
  branches:
    only:
      - staging
  configuration: Staging

  deploy:
    provider: WebDeploy
    server: [removed for brevity]
    website: [removed for brevity]
    username: [removed for brevity]
    password: [removed for brevity]
    ntlm: false
    remove_files: true
    app_offline: false

# "fall back" configuration for all other branches
# no "branches" section defined
# do not deploy at all
configuration: Debug
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the "fall back" configuration is overriding the previously set configuration. By removing this (or possibly moving it to the top of the file) you will achieve the desired outcome.